# How to use wget to download just html file with out downloading flash content(images and css sheets) ?

Tags: bash, wget

I am trying without any options like
wget www.example.com
 It still downloading more files than main html file .Is there a way to avoid downloading them ?

Comment: You should specify the file if want this explicit file. So use wget http://www.example.com/index.html

Comment: that's default behavior.

Comment: that's what I was talking about they ask without even testing the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wget will never include css, js, images or flash content. It will only download the html (if you pass an url to a html file):

```
wget http://www.myserver.de/index.html
```

This will save index.html in the current folder (and nothing more)

Comment: wget http://doregama.info/telugu-t

This is creating 3 folders with one folder containing images and another with some other htmls

Comment: [andreas@dhcp-162-183 ~]$ wget doregama.info/telugu-t 
--2013-11-02 10:10:56--  http://doregama.info/telugu-t
Resolving doregama.info (doregama.info)... 108.162.196.114, 108.162.197.114
Connecting to doregama.info (doregama.info)|108.162.196.114|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘telugu-t’

    [ <=>                                   ] 31,241      --.-K/s   in 0.1s    

2013-11-02 10:10:57 (316 KB/s) - ‘telugu-t’ saved [31241]

[andreas@dhcp-162-183 ~]$

Comment: wget only downloads a single http object by default